# How can I turn off the gamed service or more generally, any service?

Tags: macos, services, game-center

Yeah, bought a Macbook Retina, come from a Linux background where this stuff is usually a question of removing via the package manager.

Anyhow, I don't play games on this, it's purely for business/development. But I keep seeing this gamed process that came down with the Mavericks update trying to phone home.

Apart from software update, I don't really want any process phoning home, especially when I paid 2G for the damned thing.

Anyhow, anyone know how I can disable/uninstall/kill this process for good?

Comment: I didn't want to mess with the binary but turning off all settings in System Preferences>Notifications stopped the final phone homes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to completely disable the process but I've set up Little Snitch to disallow incoming / outgoing processes associated with the Game Center. It's a useful little program.

Answer (score 16):

Specifically for the `gamed` service, the following command in one of the posts about [a similar topic on the Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5497151?start=15&tstart=0) worked for me, without any need to modify plists or rename files:

```
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.gamed disabled -bool true
```

Changing "true" back to "false" will re-enable it, although I've not tried it.

Comment: looks good, lets see if apple honor the setting.

Comment: You can also run `launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.gamed.plist`. It modifies `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.$UID/overrides.plist`, which has precedence over the `Disabled` key.

Comment: For all of you who find this and will try to use this method on El Capitan, you might be disappointed. I just did the launchctl unload method and that works even on El Capitan.

Comment: Alas, SIP seems to prevent both the `defaults` and the `launchctl` method of `gamed`-disabling on Sierra (as of 10.12.6 -- though I think the  `launchctl` method may have worked on 10.12.5 and before).

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is open the damn thing and log out of Game Center, and delete whatever it still filled in.

Comment: I've never even signed in to the Game Center

Comment: Yeah, it lives at: /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/gamed

Comment: tried using launchctl as described in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105892/disable-services-in-osx-services-msc

Comment: But it doesn't show up in the process list.

Comment: @picsolve_binarytemple it won't it is a daemon and so only runs when something ttys to call it

Comment: Even if you are not signed in, the gamed process still tries to contact whatever IP.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cheap hack:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/gamed /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/gamed.inactive
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be about the only way to disable that crap. I haven't tried it yet (just blocking it's communication using a firewall) but that seems the only way to turn it off.

Comment: Cannot do that on OS X El Capitan (without system protection disabled). The launchctl way can be done though.

Answer (score 0):

In Yosemite 10.10.3 the `gamed` process can be found in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameCenterFoundation.framework/Versions/A/gamed`.

I needed to rename the process to get rid of it, the `defaults write` and `unload` suggestions didn't work.

Comment: See other [answers](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116632/237) - how does this differ?

Comment: @Mark game kit -> GCF

Answer (score 0):

Apple *really* wants this service to run:

```
# pwd
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameCenterFoundation.framework/Versions/A
# mv gamed gamed.disabled
mv: rename gamed to gamed.disabled: Operation not permitted
# rm gamed
override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel restricted,compressed for gamed? y
rm: gamed: Operation not permitted
# ls -l gamed
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  4430368 Jul  9 04:51 gamed
```

This was on El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: It's probably SIP protected